# Load same fragment with different data in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have 8 fragments with the same layout in my viewpager. The fragment contains a recycler view and a text view. My problem is that when i initiate the viewpager fragment then all the data gets loaded on the first fragment itself and nothing shows up in the rest of the fragments. Here is how i set up my adapter and viewpager in the fragment.

```
            adapter = new SelectPlayerAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager());

            //Set up the view pager.
            setupViewPager(pager);

 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter.addFragment(new PlayersFragment(), "BATSMAN 1", batsman_1);
    adapter.addFragment(new PlayersFragment(), "BATSMAN 2", batsman_2);
    adapter.addFragment(new PlayersFragment(), "BATSMAN 3", batsman_3);
    adapter.addFragment(new PlayersFragment(), "ALL-ROUNDER 1", all_rounder_1);
    adapter.addFragment(new PlayersFragment(), "ALL-ROUNDER 2", all_rounder_2);
    adapter.addFragment(new PlayersFragment(), "WICKET-KEEPER", wicket_keeper);
    adapter.addFragment(new PlayersFragment(), "BOWLER 1", bowler_1);
    adapter.addFragment(new PlayersFragment(), "BOWLER 2", bowler_2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is my Adapter class.

```
public class SelectPlayerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

Context context = null;
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<String> player_list = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson;


public SelectPlayerAdapter(Context context, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mgr) {
    super(mgr);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}


@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment player_fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("player_position_string", player_list.get(position));
    player_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return player_fragment;
}


public void addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title, ArrayList<Player> players_position_list) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    gson = new Gson();
    String players_position_string = gson.toJson(players_position_list);
    player_list.add(players_position_string);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
```

I am passing different arraylists when adding the fragments and adding them to a different arraylist in my adapter, when get item is called i get the item from the arraylist and pass it as argument to that fragment but when i run this, i get all the arguments initially only and nothing happens when I change the tabs. I tried debugging and saw that getitem is getting called 8 times initially only and nothing happens when i change the viewpager tabs. I have tried fragment newinstance method and addonpagechangelistener as well but getting the same result. Please help.

Here is my Players Fragment class.

```
public class PlayersFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView player_position_text;
private TextView player_position_number_text;
private RecyclerView players_list_view;
Bundle extra;
private String players_string;
private ArrayList<Player> player_position_list;
Gson gson;

public PlayersFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    PlayersFragment playersFragment = new PlayersFragment();
    return playersFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_player_layout, container, false);

    //Get the bundle from previous fragment.
    extra = this.getArguments();

    //If bundle contains the key players string then retrieve it.
    if(extra.containsKey("player_position_string")){

        players_string = extra.getString("player_position_string", "0");
        System.out.println("players string is " + players_string);
        gson = new Gson();

        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Player>>() {
        }.getType();
        player_position_list = gson.fromJson(players_string, type);
        System.out.println("players list is " + player_position_list);
        System.out.println("players name is " + player_position_list.get(1).getName());

    }

    //If bundle does not contain string it then display a toast.
    else
    {
        // Display toast with exception.
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was some error with getting the details. Please try again later.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    player_position_text = view.findViewById(R.id.player_position_text);
    player_position_number_text = view.findViewById(R.id.player_position_number_text);
    players_list_view = view.findViewById(R.id.players_list_view);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Where you able to do it? It would be a help if you provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I added a working demo. Please can you check this and let me know if it works.

Player.java

```
public class Player implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Player(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    protected Player(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        age = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Player> CREATOR = new Creator<Player>() {
        @Override
        public Player createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Player(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Player[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Player[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(age);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

PlayerFragment.java

```
public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PLAYERS = "arg_player";
    private Player player;

    public static PlayerFragment newInstance(Player players) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(ARG_PLAYERS, players);
        PlayerFragment fragment = new PlayerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

        public PlayerFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            if (args != null){
                this.player = args.getParcelable(ARG_PLAYERS);
            }
            if (player == null){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Player list can not be null");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_player)).setText(player.toString());
        }
    }
```

StatePagerAdapter.java

```
public class StatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Player> players;
    private List<String> titles;

    public StatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Player> players, List<String> titles) {
        super(fm);
        if (players.size() != titles.size())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sizes must be equal");
        this.players = players;
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlayerFragment.newInstance(players.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return players.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add(new Player("a", 1));
        players.add(new Player("b", 2));
        players.add(new Player("c", 3));

        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Title1", "Title2", "Title3"));

        StatePagerAdapter adapter = new StatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), players, titles);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

PREV ANS:

Can you please share your PlayersFragment class and try below code.

```
@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment player_fragment = new PlayerFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("player_position_string", player_list.get(position));
    player_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return player_fragment;
}
```

Comment: I already tried the code you mentioned. Same result. Also, i added the players fragment class. I am just printing the data i am getting in the fragment as of now for debugging purposes.

Comment: It kind of worked, but when i launch it i get first two values in console, when i select title2 then i get the third value which is name="c" and age="3" and when i select title 3, i don't get anything. After the first time when i select title 1, i get only the first value. Second value is missing and third fragment is empty.

Comment: Did you check the textviews in fragments layouts? Because I got results correct for each page that i swiped.

Comment: That is correct, it shows correctly for me too. Hmm, weird..in the oncreate method if i check it then it shows the wrong data but in onviewcreated, it works perfectly fine. I am trying to use my code with this approach now.

Comment: Because FragmentPagerAdapter creates two fragment at same time. So when you swipe next fragment, second fragment not calling onCreate because its already created but calling onCreateView because its just became visible. If this helps you please accept the answer. And you can read more about this behavior of FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: I already did. May be because of my reputation it does not show up publically but i did. Thanks a ton.